# openrdf-sesame database / triplestore in eclipse wtp project with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, eclipse-wtp, triplestore, sesame

I want to use an openrdf-sesame triplestore in an Eclipse WTP project with a Tomcat server. I need to put some sample date to this triplestore to use it in my wtp project.

If I use Tomcat without Eclipse, I have to deploy the two war-files (`openrdf-sesame.war`, `openrdf-workbench.war`) with the tomcat-manager to Tomcat. Then I can access the openrdf-workbench via `http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/` to put the sample data on the triplestore, but in Eclipse it's not possible to deploy the two war-files with the tomcat-manager.

How can I use sesame in an eclipse-wtp project inside tomcat?

**Edit:**

I tried [Jeen Broekstra answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952494/183704), but now I get a lot of errors in Eclipse.

[image: errors]

Comment: In your final product, do you want a separate sesame server to your web application? If not you can configure your web application to use the native store in combination with a SailRepository - http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/api/org/openrdf/sail/nativerdf/NativeStore.html

Comment: Yes, I have to use a separate sesame server. I think the best solution is to run an external tomcat server on different ports during development with eclipse or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* possible to deploy the standard Sesame war files from Eclipse, it's quite easy actually:

1. Go to "File -> import ... -> Web -> WAR file" and select the `openrdf-sesame.war` file.
2. Choose the appropriate Tomcat server as your target runtime and click next.
3. In the next screen (import web libraries), leave everything unchecked, click Finish.

Once you've done this, openrdf-sesame will be availabe in Eclipse as a web project, which you can deploy and run on Tomcat like any other web project.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but if I do that, I get a lot of [errors](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JOED2.png).

Comment: These errors have to do with Eclipse JSP compilation having trouble with finding custom tags. I'm not sure how to get rid of the errors, but you can just ignore them. Try running the project, it should just work.